# React router configuration for an SPA with fixed layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my first post here, hope I'm covering everything and did a search for various topics, watched some vids, read the react router docs before getting stuck. :-(

I'm working on a single page app, which has the following components:

- Layout - parent component, has two children:

  - Maps - child component
  - Events - child component, has one child component:

    - EventDetails

Trying to configure react router to keep the Layout component on the page at all times, and render Maps and Events.  Inside Events, when clicking on a link with an event_id (got the link working), it should display into EventDetails.  I can't figure out how to get the EventDetails component to display into Events, with the Layout still displaying.

I'm pretty sure I've got my routes mis-configured, or don't really understand IndexRoute completely....thanks in advance for looking.

An image and some code below of my router config.

An imgur link of a layout diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5vKk.png

And a link to the

React router config:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>

<Route path="/" component={Layout} >
    <Route path="/events/:event_id" component={EventDetail} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-router controls what should be visible by injecting component into `children` prop.

Let's imagine you have the following routes:

```
<Route path="/" component={Layout} >
    <Route path="/maps" component={Maps} />
    <Route path="/events/" component={Events}>
       <Route path="/events/:event_id" component={EventDetail}>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

With these routes react-router will automatically pass the Maps component as `children` prop in the Layout component when you are on `/maps` path or the Event component when you are on `/event`. The same thing happens for nested components/routes. Your job is to use `{this.props.children}` in render method of Root component and children components which want to display other nested components.

To sum up your Layout component render method should look like this:

```
render() {
   <div>
      <div> [LAYOUT] This part doesn't change between routes </div>
      <div>
          {this.props.children} // here I render nested component like events or maps
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

Then your Event component

```
 render() {
       <div>
          <div> [EVENT] This part doesn't change between nested event routes </div>
          <div>
              {this.props.children} // here I render nested component inside event route like EventDetails
          </div>
       </div>
    }
```

Here you have collection of lessons for react-router:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons
(Lesson 7 is your case).

`IndexRoute` is a Route component with `path="/"`